# How to structure my input vector for Kerras lstm text generation model for one hot encoded charachter based input

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to train a Keras lstm model for generation of potry I encode my data as sequence of charachters where each charachter is one hot encoded. I am using many-to-one model so my input is a 2-dimentional array like this one.
[[0,1,0], [1,0,0], ... ,[1,0,0]] Where each vector represents one time step, I want to have 512 charachters fead to each of the lstm cells and have the last one predict the same one hot encoded vector with prediction of the next charachter.

How should I split my data into batches and timesteps?

Thank you

```
data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(data, targets,
                               length=n_timesteps,
                               batch_size=n_batches)
model.fit_generator(data_gen ,epochs=100, shuffle=False, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need a sliding window over the input. *How many characters do you look at before predicting the next?* For this purpose, there is [TimeseriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#timeseriesgenerator) in utils that will turn your 2d data into a 3d windowed input for training. It will generate the input and the target of that sequence of characters for you.

Comment: Thank you this is exacly what I need, but how the hell  do you actualy use it?  
I changed my question and added the version I am using right now:

Comment: broken link costs users time

Comment: links break over time, you can't expect community answers to maintain active link checks